# Pyspark counter field, groupby and increment by 1

Tags: group-by, count, pyspark, counter, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe is as follows:

```
cola, colb
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 5
```

I want to add a column `count`:

```
cola, colb, count
1,     2,    1
1,     3,    2
2,     1,    1
2,     5,    2
```

Need to groupby colA and set count to 1 for first record, then increment each successive row by 1.

I tried to use a window function but that applies the same count for all records in colA without the increment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already figured out that a window function is the way to go. Maybe you haven't used the [rank](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rank) function.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

l = [(1       , 2),
(1      , 3  ),
(1      , 2  ),
(2      , 1  ),
(2      , 5)]

columns = ['cola', 'colb']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

w = Window.partitionBy('cola').orderBy('colb')

df = df.withColumn('count', F.rank().over(w))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+-----+ 
|cola|colb|count| 
+----+----+-----+ 
|   1|   2|    1| 
|   1|   2|    1| 
|   1|   3|    3| 
|   2|   1|    1| 
|   2|   5|    2|
+----+----+-----+
```

In case you don't want gaps after equal rows, you should use the [dense_rank](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank) function.

Comment: was looking for the similar information. thank you!